# file_field_tag : what was the original file name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My site allows users to upload csv files for processing.  It all works
fine, but on the response I'd like to report something like "Your file
abc.csv processed OK".

Unfortunately I cannot seem to find the actual original file name in
the params, even though Firebug tells me it's part of the post.

Any tips?

Thanks....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using debug on the results of your form.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debug

Comment: I dont see how that helps.  I can tell the filename is not in the params hash by looking at the log.

Comment: I thought it might help breakdown where to look. After a little digging I found it in params[:your_file_field_name].original_filename.

Comment: Yes - just found that myself!  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As Jarrod mentions in the comments above.  Use params[:file].original_filename

Funny thing is, my form has two file upload tags (file1 and file2).  One comes in as a ActionController::UploadedTempfile and the other ActionController::UploadedStringIO.

This may be a rails bug but it doesn't matter to me as both have the original_filename method.

Comment: The UploadedTempfile is probably Rails creating a temp file for an upload that's too large to keep in memory.